# como mostrar multiples imagenes en la vista de detalle en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

quiero mostrar las paginas de un comic en la vista de destalle.

////////Vista

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="@Url.Action("PaginasComics", "Comics", new {IdC = Model.Pages})" />
    </div>
</div>
```

////////Controlador

```
    public ActionResult PaginasComics(string IdPagina)
    {
        var PaginasC = db.Paginas.Where(x => x.IdPaginaC.ToString() == IdPagina).FirstOrDefault();
        return File(PaginasC.Paginas, "imagen/jpeg", string.Format("{0}.jpg", IdPagina));

    }
```

/////// Models

```
public class Comics
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int IdComics { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public byte[] Portada { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechadeEstreno { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PaginasComics> Pages { get; set; }


}

public class PaginasComics
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int IdPaginaC { get; set; }
    public byte[] Paginas {get; set;}
    public int Id_Comic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: pero como piensas moverte entre paginas ?

Comment: en el linq filtrar por la pagina, pero no le pasas el IdComics, este deberia se run parametro del action

Comment: soy nuevo ultilizando ASP.NET MVC, tengo conocimiento semi-basico y nunca antes habia trabajado con imagenes, tienes algun ejemplo?

Comment: @WilmerVasquezD.Leon revisa este workshop, te dará un buen punto de partida: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: no hay ejemplo de lo que planteas, por lo general las imagenes se muestran en un  thumbnail https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail, o quizas en un carrousell o slider

Comment: algo que noto incorrecto es que en PaginasComics() define el nombre del parametro IdPagina, pero despues en el Url.Action() usas IdC, eso no es correcto

Comment: @LeandroTuttini fue un error, se me olvido arreglarlo a la hora de subir el post, lo tengo tal cual como dices, pero igual no me funciona, ahora estoy viendo si re-estructuro la DB para ver si puedo llamar las imagines de otra forma

Comment: @fredyfx me ayudo el video a nivel de organizar mi proyecto, pero aun sigo con el mismo problema de que no esta mostrando las imagenes que guardo en el `public ICollection<PaginasComics> Pages { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo hay algo raro en la estructura que planteas, porque en la vista haces una llamada con un action al controlador pasando Model.Pages que es segun lo explicado ICollection, pero esa accion recibe un string IdPagina, asique eso ya va a ser un problema, si he entendido lo que quieres hacer, seria hacer esa llamada correctamente para todas las paginas del comic usando un bucle for en la vista con Razor tal que:

```
@foreach(var pag in Model.Pages){
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="@Url.Action("PaginasComics", "Comics", new {IdPagina= pag.IdPaginaC})" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Nota, no tengo en cuenta la parte HTML eso ya lo ajustas como veas en la pantalla.

Espero que te ayude algo

Answer (score 0):

Al fin tuve que hacerle una modificación para que si me pudiera guardar las imágenes en el `ICollection`

Metodo al momento de crear el comic

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Titulo,FechadeEstreno")] Comics comics, HttpPostedFileBase imagenPortada, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Paginas)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                        if (Paginas != null)
                        {
                            var list = new List<PaginasComics>();
                            foreach (var pagina in Paginas)
                            {
                                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(pagina.InputStream))
                                {
                                var data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(pagina.ContentLength);
                                var img = new PaginasComics { Id_Comic = comics.IdComics};
                                img.Paginas = data;
                                list.Add(img);
                                }
                            }
                        comics.Pages = list;
                        }
                db.Comics.Add(comics);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(comics);
        }
```

Método que llama las imágenes

```
public ActionResult PaginasComics(string IdPagina)
        {
var PaginasC = db.Paginas.Where(x => x.IdPaginaC.ToString() == IdPagina).FirstOrDefault();
            if (PaginasC == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return File(PaginasC.Paginas, "imagen/jpeg");
        }
```

Vista

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Pages)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img src="@Url.Action("PaginasComics","Comics", new { IdPagina = item.IdPaginaC })" alt="imagen" />
        </div>
    }
```